# c++: Why does this print statement deallocate the value stored inside of a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, googletest, googlemock

I have a googletest that is meant to unittest a function that calls an external fortran function by mocking the external call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class InterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test {};
class MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs, (int*));
};

void testfunc_pointer(MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs* func_interface) {
  int testscalar = 123;
  func_interface->fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(&testscalar);
}
TEST_F(InterfaceTest, TestFuncInterfacePointerArgs) {
  MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;
  int* passed_scalar_pointer = nullptr;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::_))
    .WillOnce(testing::DoAll(
        testing::SaveArg<0>(&passed_scalar_pointer)
    ));
  testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface);
  std::cout << *passed_scalar_pointer << std::endl; //prints 123

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I want to verify what value the fortran function is being called with, which works fine. However, simply adding another cout call before the `std::cout << *passed_scalar_pointer << std::endl;` statement suddenly causes the program to deallocate the value stored in the original pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class InterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test {};
class MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs, (int*));
};

void testfunc_pointer(MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs* func_interface) {
  int testscalar = 123;
  func_interface->fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(&testscalar);
}
TEST_F(InterfaceTest, TestFuncInterfacePointerArgs) {
  MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;
  int* passed_scalar_pointer = nullptr;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::_))
    .WillOnce(testing::DoAll(
        testing::SaveArg<0>(&passed_scalar_pointer)
    ));
  testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface);
  std::cout << "testprint" << std::endl;
  std::cout << *passed_scalar_pointer << std::endl; //prints random integer

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

How can a simple print statement cause such behaviour? What exactly does `std::cout << "testprint" << std::endl;` do that could modify a value that is stored inside of a variable?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior, so this type of thing is to be expected.  `testscalar` is local to `testfunc_pointer` so returning a pointer to it leaves that pointer as a dangling pointer.  Derefencing that pointer has undefined behavior.

Comment: Seems like you have a pointer to a function local value `int testscalar = 123`. When that function ends, the pointer is invalid (dangling).

Comment: A sufficiently smart compiler with all the warnings turned on and cranked up may be able to warn you about mistakes like this.

Comment: Passing the local value testscalar by reference would be a workaround, right?

Comment: @Simon unfortunately I have to pass the pointer because I am calling an external fortran function, which only accepts pointers to values as input arguments. Writing the values to the heap is also not an optimal solution since my fortran function stores the passed values itself and I don't want to needlessly take up memory in my program

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you have any idea how the contents of the pointer can be verified in this test? Unfortunately I don't see a way to access these values once the function returns and deallocates the pointer targets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to verify what value the fortran function is being called with,
> which works fine. However, simply adding another cout call before the
> `std::cout << *passed_scalar_pointer << std::endl;` statement suddenly
> causes the program to deallocate the value stored in the original
> pointer:

Here is your code run with [address sanitizer](https://godbolt.org/z/5hrfdo5qM).

Basically problem is that you are passing a pointer to local variable which lifetime ends when `testfunc_pointer` execution ends. So this is source of UB in your test.

IMO your test is invalid since tries to verify implementation detail (value of `testscalar` inside a `testfunc_pointer`). It is impossible to fix your test since `testfunc_pointer` is oversimplified and can't tel what actually test should do.

By filing gaps (I ca be wrong), this should have following form:

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

class InterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test { };

class MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs, (int*));
};

int testfunc_pointer(MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs* func_interface)
{
    int testscalar;
    func_interface->fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(&testscalar);

    return testscalar + 55;
}

TEST_F(InterfaceTest, WhenFortranFunctionProvidesValueResultIsGraterBy55)
{
    MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;

    const int fortranValue = 11;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::NotNull()))
        .WillOnce(testing::Invoke([fortranValue](auto* p) { *p = fortranValue; }));

    EXPECT_THAT(testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface), fortranValue + 55);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5qTscK47G

If you expecting that Fortran function should get value (not provide a value) by pointer, the proper solution is:

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

class InterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test { };

class MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs, (int*));
};

void testfunc_pointer(MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs* func_interface)
{
    int testscalar = 123;
    func_interface->fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(&testscalar);
}

TEST_F(InterfaceTest, FortranFunctionProvidesValue123)
{
    MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::Pointee(123)));
    testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G5jaW3c91 [failure example](https://godbolt.org/z/ba4WYzTbe)

### Side note:

Do not use `std::cout` in tests! Use assertion to express what is expected. If it fails gtest will print actual value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the `SaveArgPointee` functionality instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class InterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test {};
class MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs, (int*));
};

void testfunc_pointer(MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs* func_interface) {
  int testscalar = 123;
  func_interface->fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(&testscalar);
}
TEST_F(InterfaceTest, TestFuncInterfacePointerArgs) {
  MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;
  int passed_scalar = 0;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::_))
    .WillOnce(testing::DoAll(
        testing::SaveArgPointee<0>(&passed_scalar)
    ));
  testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface);
  std::cout << passed_scalar << std::endl; //prints 123

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```